# Send data to a command using an specific frequency

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, timestamps

I want to do a bash script that reads a file that each line contains a timestamp and a value, and send the line to another command with the same frequency as the data.

For example, if I have these lines:

```
1499108150         26
1499108156         100
```

I would need to send the first line in a certain moment, and the second line 6 seconds after the previous one.

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the file being continuously updated?

Comment: It could be, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

previous=0
while read tstamp value
do
  if [[ $previous -eq 0 ]]
  then
    echo sending "$value"
  else
    sleep $((tstamp - previous))
    echo sending "$tstamp $value"
  fi
  previous=$tstamp
done < input
```

Put that into a script and make it executable.

Comment: This script works, but does not send the complete line, only the value. How can I send the whole line? Thanks!

Comment: I overlooked that in the question; sorry! Just a matter of adding $tstamp to the output, as I just did in the edit to the answer.